# Make Android google maps api black/white

Tags: android, google-maps, android-theme

I know this is possible on the JavaScript version on Google maps, and found a Q/A on here how to do it via the web biased version.  But I want to do that to the maps that will be part of my android app. As it would fit way better with the theme I got going though the rest of the app if I could make the maps appear in a green and black. does the android version support this like the JavaScript version does? and how would i go about setting it to do that if it does?

Answer (score 0):

No the android version of google maps does not support this function.

This post http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/14/android-recipe-3-sliding-menu-layers-and-filters/ shows how to use a colorfilter to make an arbtrary image black and white and should be able to be applied on top of a map.

Comment: I looked at that link and it only appears to explain how to hook in to the api of that sliding menu class to create a tint-able overlay so unless I'm missing something there doesn't appear to be a way to do their tinting on a view or fragment that is not using that menu library, so I still need more info as to how to apply that.

Comment: The tint overlay code is applied using methods in the view class (setLayerPaint(API17) and setLayerType(API11)). Every view will have these methods.

Comment: Also, adding an overlay is still not the same as the black and white feature offered in web api maps for v3